# How Do I Encode a Unicode String in Base36 in PHP?

Tags: php, url, encode, base36

I have learned how to Base16 encode a string in PHP, but how do I Base36 encode and decode a string in PHP?

Note I need this to make the string work in URLs.

BONUS: And if you know how to compress the string slightly first before doing the Base36, that would be even cooler! :)

Comment: what are you trying to make to work in urls !

Comment: You might also look into an URL-safe version of Base64 encoding/decoding ( [here's a PHP version](http://php.net/base64-encode#82506) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google told me this: http://darklaunch.com/2009/07/31/base36-encode-and-decode-using-php-with-example-base36-encode-base36-decode

Anyway, [base64](http://php.net/base64_encode) should fit your needs if you want to use it inside an URL.

Bonus: [gzcompress()](http://php.net/gzcompress) and [gzuncompress()](http://php.net/gzuncompress) ;) (Zlib extension must be installed).

Comment: But I thought that Base64 creates extra characters in the URL that could be construed as query parameters. Wouldn't that be a problem? What's the resolution in such a case?

Comment: I know the base64 encoded string can end with one or two = (equals), but I think it's not a problem if you use it as a GET value (&var=base64_encoded_value_here==). I'm not 100% sure, but based on this, I believe it should.

Comment: Base64 uses slashes (/) and plus (+). The easiest way to make it work in a url is to replace / and + with _ and - (`strtr(base64str, '/+', '_-')`). See Python's urlsafe_b64encode

Comment: base_convert() does not work well with binary (including non ASCII symbols) strings of arbitrary length

Comment: @Volomike If you use `strtr( base64_encode( $input ), '/+', '_-' )` like @mcrumley suggested it will work with your unicode strings (or in fact any binary string). Then, at the other end, use `base64_decode( strtr( $input, '_-', '/+' ) )` to retrieve the original unicode (or binary) data.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a very long time ago but I assume it hasn't changed since ;)

```
function number2ascii($input='', $base=10){                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    $length = strlen($input);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    $dec = base_convert(255, 10, $base);                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    $chars = strlen($dec);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    $output = '';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i+=$chars){                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        $text = substr($input, $i, $chars);                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        $dec = base_convert($text, $base, 10);                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        $output .= chr($dec);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return $output;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  


function ascii2number($input='', $base=10){                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    $length = strlen($input);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    $dec = base_convert(255, 10, $base);                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    $chars = strlen($dec);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    $output = '';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        $dec = ord($input[$i]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        $number = base_convert($dec, 10, $base);                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        $number = str_pad($number, $chars, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        $output .= $number.' ';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return $output;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data I have is Unicode, not ASCII. I should have stated that, however.